# Facebook Graph API Page Public Content Access procedure

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am planning to use Facebook feeds from some public pages which don't belong to me. For example WHO Facebook page. I am planning to use these posts from multiple pages and show on a website. My question is, whether this is even possible with all kind of crazy security policies in place? Since Facebook is allowing to embed public posts, I am assuming we can achieve this somehow. If I have to create page/app myself and get it reviewed by Facebook, anyone got any link on how to get this done?